# What do you refer to a chart/graph designer as?

Tags: single-word-requests

It seems like another branch of statistics that is complete enough to deserve its own specialty name.

Comment: This is only obliquely related to statistics in that it works with statistical data, but isn't concerned at all with the collection of that data. "Information Design" is what you're after.

Comment: I call them GRAPHic Designer. Get it? Heheh. On topic, in my company the division for that is called "Data Warehouse", which job includes analyzing data and producing meaningful data from it (which includes graphs and pie charts).

Comment: How about _diagrammer_? (not an official word)

Answer (score 1):

Looking to Edward Tufte for inspiration, the term "data-visualizer" seems appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The sub-field is called Computational and Graphical Statistics. Here is a link to the current issue of their society's professional journal.

http://amstat.tandfonline.com/loi/jcgs#/toc/ucgs20/current